# JavaFX TableView all fields are empty

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have been at this for a while now and can't seem to solve it, I'm attempting to populate a tableview from my database, the tableview fills with the right amount of rows however all of the cells remain blank. 
The values are Integer, String, Double, Int, String
[image: the blank rows in the tableview]

This is the class in which the tableview is loaded

```
public class FXMLDocumentTakeOrderController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private TableView <Item> tableviewLightMeals;
    @FXML private TableColumn<?, ?> colItemNumber;
    @FXML private TableColumn<?, ?> colItemName;
    @FXML private TableColumn<?, ?> colItemCategory;
    @FXML private TableColumn<?, ?> colItemPrice;
    @FXML private TableColumn<?, ?> colItemIngredients;
    ObservableList <Item> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        colItemNumber.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemid"));
        colItemName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemname"));
        colItemCategory.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemcategory"));
        colItemPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemprice"));
        colItemIngredients.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("itemingredients"));
        loadMenuItems();
    }

    public void loadMenuItems(){
            Connection con;
            try{
            String username = "register01";
            String password = "jxncjdshvbfdkhg";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://mydatabaselink";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            Statement sqlStat = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = sqlStat.executeQuery("select * from menu where itemcategory='1'" + ";");
            while(rs.next()){
                data.add(new Item(
                rs.getInt("itemid"),
                rs.getString("itemname"),
                rs.getInt("itemcategory"),
                rs.getDouble("itemprice"),
                rs.getString("itemingredients")
                ));
            tableviewLightMeals.setItems(data);
                //System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(Item));
            }
            sqlStat.close();
            rs.close();
          }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.out.println("Error on Building Data");             
          }
    }
}
```

and this is my Item Class

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int category;
    private double price;
    private String ingredients;

    public Item (int id, String name, int category, double price, String ingredients) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.price = price;
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    public void setItemId (int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setItemName (String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setItemCategory (int category){
        this.category = category;
    }
    public void setItemPrice (double price){
        this.price = price;
    }
    public void setItemIngredients (String ingredients){
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }
    // Getters
    public int getItemId (){
        return id;
    }
    public String getItemName (){
        return name;
    }
    public int getItemCategory (){
        return category;
    }
    public double getItemPrice (){
        return price;
    }
    public String getItemIngredients (){
        return ingredients;
    }
}
```

I think my getters are right, as I have seen in another persons question on here and it is a very similar issue however I still have been unable to work it out.

Comment: the name in the propertyValueFactory looks wrong: your property name is "itemId" but you create a factory for "itemid" (note the case of the second part)

Comment: I think it has to be like that as thats the column name in the database and the result set

Comment: the table is not interested in your database - all that matters is the name of the properties in the Item ;)

Comment: You are a legend! Thank you